# Triggering action when QTableView selection is changed

Tags: python, qtableview, selectionchanged, pyside6

I am trying to trigger the action when cell selection of QTableView. I am using the selectionChanged but it triggers the action only for the first time and changing the cell selection is not triggering the action again. What is that I am doing wrong.

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
def __init__(self, data):
    super(TableModel, self).__init__()
    self._data = data

def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
        return str(value)

def rowCount(self, index):
    return self._data.shape[0]

def columnCount(self, index):
    return self._data.shape[1]

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    # section is the index of the column/row.
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return str(self._data.columns[section])

        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return str(self._data.index[section])


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

    data = pd.DataFrame([
      [1, 9, 2],
      [1, 0, -1],
      [3, 5, 2],
      [3, 3, 2],
      [5, 8, 9],
    ], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5'])

    self.model = TableModel(data)
    self.table.setModel(self.model)
    selectionModel = self.table.selectionModel()
    selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.printLocation())
    self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

def printLocation(self):
    print(self.table.currentIndex())

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: change to `electionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.printLocation)`

Comment: OMG! What a stupid mistake. Thanks.